# How can I evaluate a string inline in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

I have a cfg file whose content is like below:

```
input.cfg:

a_tag=ABC
b_tag=DEF
```

I have a shell script like below:

```
source input.cfg


update_input() {
local tag_id=$1
local tag_replace=${tag_id}_tag

echo ${tag_replace}
}

input_list="a b"

for input in ${input_list}
do
    update_input ${input}
done
```

Here I get the below output:

```
a_tag
b_tag
```

However I need to get the output as ABC and DEF as defined in input.cfg and cannot figure out a way to do the same. Can someone help, thanks!

Comment: `echo "${!tag_replace}"`